# Automatic texts in short description of WooCommerce products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am trying to create an automatic text in the sort description of the WooCommerce articles and put the price of the product in this message.

***For example:*** "buying this product you get (price) bonus."

Can I put the brand of the product in this message too?

***For example:*** "sold by genericshop"

code :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'single_product_short_description', 10, 1 );
function single_product_short_description( $post_excerpt )
{
  global $product; 
  if ( is_single( $product->id ) )
  $post_excerpt = '<div class="product-message"><p>' . __( "Article only 
  available in the store.", "woocommerce" ) . '</p></div>' . $post_excerpt;
  return $post_excerpt;
}
```

Comment: try some codes and post it here then only we can offer help.

Comment: I was able to put the brand. Now I only need the price.